# Freeing a struct of int*

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

I have a struct which i am storing an array of integers defined as:

```
    typedef struct {
    int* numArr;
    int counter;
    }NumberArr;
```

I have initialised it to be: `(int*)malloc(sizeof(int))`
and reallocated when i need to add a number using: `num.numArr = realloc(num.numArr, sizeof(int) * (counter+1));`

I am having issue with calling free for this struct.
I have tried:

```
   void free_data(NumberArr num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.counter; i++) {
            free(num.numArr[i]);
        }
        free(num.numArr);
   }
```

When I do this i get an error message, saying it isn't type void pointer. but i dont know what to do to make it one so I can free it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `numArr` is a single pointer (`*`). You just need to free it once. Your function `free_date` parameter should be a pointer to `NumberArr`, and then just pass the address of your variable like `&var`.

```c
void free_data(NumberArr *num) {
    free(num->numArr);
}
```

The concept you are using is used while freeing double-pointer `int **`.